# Tomcat Context level WebAppLoader Repositories (reloading)

Tags: java, tomcat

Given a context with a custom [Loader class](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/loader.html) / [WebappLoader](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappLoader.html) which uses addRepository() to load additional jar files whilst during application start, is it possible to reload the (possibly modified) jar files when the context is reloaded?

- Can a  be specified as 'reloadable'?
- Are jars loaded by a Context level Loader unloaded when the context is stopped?
- A good description of the clearReferencesThreadLocals config attribute?